# Firebase bucket / axios url in request body decoding issue

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, axios, urlencode

Interesting issue when using Firebase buckets and axios in a JS environments.

When I upload a file into a bucket and send the file link returned by firebase to server in a request body, the link is auto decoded in the server.

1. Upload a file to bucket from web
2. Firebase returns a link: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o/[POINTER]%2Fimages%2F[FILE_NAME])`

*note the url encoded **%2F** that firebase uses around the **'images'***

3. Save this to DB via a Cloud Function call by using axios.post()

*Using `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}` due to Cloud Function limitations here. The url is nested in a JSON object as a String.*

4. When this request is picked up in the Cloud Function, the URL in the object has been automatically urldecoded, resulting in:

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o/[POINTER]/images/[FILE_NAME])`

*note the **/** around the **'images'***

**Problem**: Firebase doesn't return the file when %2F is replaced with / in the URL, only returning error:

```
Invalid HTTP method/URL pair.
```

I understand that I have only one option here, and it is to prevent this String to be URL decoded during the client-server axios call. Since I am using the mentioned headers, I'm not sure how this can be achieved.

**Side quest**: Why does Firebase enforce the urlencode this strongly and doesn't return the file independently of the representation of the path to file (encoded or not)?